# R Plot assigning points color to row names

Tags: r, plot

Here is my data frame:

```
      Z            melting.point
AIN  -1.7596934    -0.3184053
AIP  -1.3968700     0.2290334
AIAs -0.5805174     1.8950577
```

The first columns replaces with the chemical names of the observations the initial default in R:

```
     compounds      Z                 melting.point
1       AIN        -1.7596934        -0.3184053
2       AIP        -1.3968700         0.2290334
3      AIAs        -0.5805174         1.8950577
```

So, based on the first data frame, I'd like to run a command such as:

```
plot(melting.point ~ Z, col = rownames(dat), data = dat)
```

but I get an error message:

```
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'compounds' not found
```

Is there a way of coloring the points based on the row names of a data frame?

Comment: the error seems to be caused by the `compounds` column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cant reproduce your error but rownames(dat) is not a suitable colorname. So, try it with  a factor or a numeric vector.

```
plot(melting.point ~ Z, col = as.factor(rownames(dat)),data = dat)
plot(melting.point ~ Z, col = 1:nrow(dat),data = dat)
```